# How to use QOpenGLWidget in PyQt5 without freezing the app when launched from PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an app using PyQt5, but whenever I try to incorporate a `QOpenGLWidget` (or derived class), my app freezes (Windows title bar says "Not Responding"). Below is a complete program demonstrating the problem. When I set `show_gl_widget` to `True`, the launched app freezes.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QOpenGLWidget, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QMainWindow()
central_widget = QWidget(parent=main_window)
main_window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
layout = QHBoxLayout()
show_gl_widget = False  # Set show_gl_widget to True to see the problem
if show_gl_widget:  # Window shows, but hangs with "Not responding" this way
    gl_widget = QOpenGLWidget(parent=main_window.centralWidget())
    layout.addWidget(gl_widget)
else:  # Works OK this way
    label = QLabel(parent=main_window.centralWidget(), text='Hey!')
    layout.addWidget(label)
main_window.centralWidget().setLayout(layout)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm experiencing this problem on Windows 10, using 64-bit python 3.6.2. I have not tried other environments.

**EDIT**: The program runs correctly for me when I run it from the command line, but not when I run from the PyCharm IDE. Why would the application freeze when running from the PyCharm IDE?

Comment: I have tested it in linux and runs correctly, you could run it via cmd to see if it generates any error message, you could also explain how you installed pyqt5.

Comment: my output: https://imgur.com/a/pGF9B

Comment: @eyllanesc I installed pyqt5 by "pip3 install pyqt5". I think I remember that pip installed a binary wheel, rather than performing a full build.

Comment: Pip installs the requirements of the library if it finds them, but does not install dlls as they should compile them for each system, I think you're missing the opengl dlls.

Comment: @I've got PyOpenGL and PyOpenGL-accelerate already installed. I'll try testing some other GL apis next.

Comment: I've just tested another python app that uses GLFW, and it's working great. So it can't be a matter of missing general OpenGL DLLs. @eyllanesc did you mean the Qt OpenGL dlls? I see Qt5OpenGL.dll under <python>/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin/

Comment: OK. When I run from the command line it works OK. I should have run from the command line like @eyllanesc suggested at first. But when I run from the PyCharm IDE it freezes. I sure would like to be able to run from the IDE.

Comment: I have seen in many similar problems in Pycharm on windows, I run it in linux from pycharm and it works great. :P

Comment: PyCharm was sorta fun for a few months, until this deal-breaking moment. I'm going back to Eclipse/PyDev, which does not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One answer turns out to be "drag pycharm to your other monitor".

I use two monitors with an extended desktop. I was using the PyCharm IDE on my secondary monitor, in the right half of my extended desktop when I observed this problem. If I launch the app from the second monitor, whether from PyCharm, Eclipse, or the command line, the app freezes. If I use any of those methods to launch from the left monitor, the app runs OK.

I suspect this is a bug of PyQt5/QOpenGLWidget. PyCharm is not to blame here.